# XQuery to insert Parent and Child nodes

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to replace a node with some text along with a child node inside it. Below is my XQuery. I am not getting the desired result.

```
for $x in collection('articles')//Doc[Title/@No='Article 20']
  return replace value of node $x/Desc with "Article on Molecular Physics 
  <Date @d='20130805'/> in continuation with Part 1."
```

Expecting-

```
....
<Desc>Article on Molecular Physics 
  <Date @d='20130805'/> in continuation with Part 1.</Desc>
....
```

But I am getting-

```
....
<Desc>Article on Molecular Physics 
  &lt;Date @d='20130805'/&gt; in continuation with Part 1.</Desc>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To  get the desired result, I first deleted the node and then inserted it as follows-

```
 let $c := <Desc>Article on Molecular Physics <Date d='20130805'/> in continuation with Part 1.</Desc>
 for $x in collection('articles')//Doc[Title/@No='Article 20']
     return 
     (
         delete node $x/Desc,
         insert node $c after $x/Title 
     )
```

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you're including the new XML element in a string, it's being treated like one; i.e. escaped. Try replacing the string with a sequence of the nodes you want in the element, like so:

```
for $x in collection('articles')//Doc[Title/@No='Article 20']
  return replace value of node $x/Desc with 
  ("Article on Molecular Physics ", <Date d='20130805'/>, " in continuation with Part 1.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But not getting the desired result. `"Article on Molecular Physics "` only this part is being inserted :(

Comment: Ah right - looks like you can't provide structured XML in the arguments to `replace value` (and have it do what you'd want); that's not great. Looks like you have the best solution in your own answer then.